# How create several xml files and date tagging them?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

this applications sends a request to an API that returns data. I want to save that data to xml files. 
The issue is that every time i run the application i want to create a new xml file and not replace the current "c:\temp\xml.xml". Preferably i would like them to be named by the current Date so instead of 1 xml.xml i want 20160810.xml, and the next day when i run the application i would want another xml-file named 20160811.xml. How do i do that?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Send HTTPrequest
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxx");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/people/peoples?Firstname=Adam");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var person = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Persons>>().Result;

                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                foreach (var i in person)
                {
                    XmlElement el = (XmlElement)xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Employee"));
                    el.SetAttribute("EmployeeID", i.Peopleid);
                    el.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Firstname")).InnerText = i.FirstName;
                    el.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Lastname")).InnerText = i.LastName;
                    el.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Address")).InnerText = i.LocationName;

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}:\t{2}\t-{3}", i.FirstName, i.LastName, i.Peopleid, i.LocationName );
                    xmldoc.Save("c:\\temp\\xml.xml");
                }

            }
        }


    }

class Persons
{
    public string Peopleid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: So your question is "How do I convert the current date to string in C#"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime.Now gives the current date and time, so modify your saving to

```
xmldoc.Save("c:\\temp\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml");
```